# TypeORM: Migrations first or entity first

Tags: database, database-design, typeorm

I have a bit of debate with my teammate if what is better, my preference is to create the entity first then the migration because it is more productive than manually creating migrations.

What are the pros and cons of the two approaches?

1. Creating the migrations first then the entity by running `typeorm migration:create`
2. Create the entity first then the migrations by running `typeorm migration:generate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice to avoid bugs and time wasting is to create entities first to generate the migrations files after using `typeorm migration:generate`.

Creating the migrations manually using `typeorm migration:create` is a good practice too but it takes a long time and could be a source of bugs, especially concerning the columns types.

Generating migrations is also useful when you need to alter a table or columns, you don't need to search the modifications on your own.

Finally, you must already know it but **never** use synchronize in production.